# Print a View Field in Twig

Tags: views, 8, theming

I have to convert the following D7 to D8 in my view twig file. I tried the following but its not working.

**D7 Code :**

```
<?php print $view->result[$id]->field_field_document_upload[0]["rendered"]["#file"]->filesize; ?>
```

**D8 code in Twig :**

```
   {{ view.result[id].field_field_document_upload[0]["rendered"]["#file"].filesize }}
```

What's the issue

Comment: You'd have to debug it to validate that is the correct structure to use in the file.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say without knowing what exact template you are overriding, but you can't really convert your old PHP print statements to twig just like that.

What you can do however is put `{{ dump() }}` into your twig file, which is the twig equivalent to `var_dump()` in PHP. This will output all your available variables.

More info on `{{ dump() }}` [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html).